Multiple producer single consumer queue usecase
I am relatively new to Python and this is the usecase i am trying to solve as part of the learning.
There will be multiple threads calling a callback function.  If the event is not set, the callbacks just get queued. And once the event is set, we must first call all the pending callbacks that got queued. If the event is set, there is no need to queue the callback but just execute the func directly.
This is more like a multiple producer single consumer problem. I tried solving it with a single lock and multiple locks but that did not work as we need a shared pipeline. So, I am trying to use queues. Also, since this is FIFO queue, the callbacks would get executed in the order it was inserted.
This is what I came up with:
import queue
import threading
import concurrent.futures
import time

pipeline = queue.Queue()

class EventWrapper():
    def __init__(self, ev):
        self._ev = ev

    def set(self):
        self._ev.set()
        consumer()

    def __getattr__(self, name):
        # return default for other methods.
        return getattr(self._ev, name)

def reg_cb():
    print("Hey, I am a cb")

def producer(myEvent, i):
    if not myEvent.is_set():
        print("Thread %d registered cb" %i)
        pipeline.put(reg_cb)
    else:
        print("Event is already set, so I am directly calling cb")
        reg_cb()

def consumer():
    print("Event is now set")
    while not pipeline.empty():
        func = pipeline.get()
        func()

def main():
    myEvent = EventWrapper(threading.Event())
    threads = []

    for i in range(15):
        t = threading.Thread(target=producer, args=(myEvent, i,))
        t.start()
        time.sleep(1)
        threads.append(t)
        if i == 5:
            # call's EventWrapper's set() method.
            myEvent.set()

    for t in threads:
        t.join()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()

It solves the basic case.

But i know, i am missing a lot of cases. what all am i missing (considering deadlock) ?

How to pass args to reg_cb method, something like pipeline.put(reg_cb, args) and let reg_cb do some stuff?

How can i improve the design ?

Let's say - a lot of callbacks from multiple threads come, we checked if not myEvent.is_set() in producer but event got set exactly after the check, this behavior is not describable.

Would there be any possibility of a thread registering callback twice ?

In case if i want to ensure the callbacks don't just wait excessively wait in the queue, i could have a queue size limit. Would that just be enough ?


Sorry, if the questions or something is not clear, will keep updating the question based on the responses, thank you.

partial function

nothing can be improved without a use-case, once you have a use-case you then try to make it just good enough to satisfy the use-case, then you stop improving it. for example you cannot satisfy the fourth point. if the function was not re-entrant then it needs a lock, and it wouldn't matter which thread calls it, but if it was re-entrant then why don't you want the other thread to execute it concurrently after the event is set ? maybe it now becomes non re-entrant after the event, but what if two threads were executing it when the event was set ? should they both now stop executing it ?


How to pass args to reg_cb method, something like pipeline.put(reg_cb,
args) and let reg_cb do some stuff?

You can either post a tuple to the queue, with the first element being the callable, and the remainder the arguments to pass - but, better than that, you can wrap your call with a functools.partial call itself - that will take care of all edge cases for arguments passing, and you won't need to reinvent the wheel should you want to pass named arguments, "**kwargs", etc...:
from functools import partial
...
def producer(myEvent, i):
    if not myEvent.is_set():
        print("Thread %d registered cb" %i)
        pipeline.put(partial(reg_cb, i))
    ...


def reg_cb(thread_id):
    print(f"Hey, I am a cb called from thread {thread_id}")

# And no need to any changes in the "consumer code" - 
# partial return zero-argument callable, 
# with the `i` argument embedded to be used in a lazy way. 


How can i improve the design ?

One outstanding thing that looks strange there is the "consumer" being started inside one of the producer threads, just when the event is set. I think people would expect to have consumer  running in its own thread, and simply wait for the event before starting the consuming loop:

pipeline = queue.Queue()
sentinel = object()

...

class EventWrapper():
    ...

    def set(self):
        self._ev.set()
        # consumer()  <- don't. Setting the event should be enough

...

def consumer(event):
    event.wait()
    print("Event is now set")
    while not pipeline.empty():
        func = pipeline.get()
        if func is sentinel:  # "Poison pill" pattern
            break
        func()
...

def main():
    raw_event = threading.Event()
    myEvent = EventWrapper(raw_event)
    threads = []
    consumer_thread = threading.Thread(target=consumer, args=(raw_event,))
    for i in range(15):
         ...

    for t in threads:
        t.join()
    pipeline.put(sentinel)
    consumer_thread.join()

Also, do you really need to call the callback directly once the event is set?
Keeping the pattern of simply enqueueing the callbacks after the event is set would be more elegant - and the callback itself doesn't need to worry about race conditions in resources it might manipulate.  If the callback can be processed in parallel, having the "consumer" dispatch concurrent calls to the callback (perhaps by changing everything to use concurrent.futures would feel better than having the callback fit the "double role" of being called "ad hoc" and being called with enqueued data.
If new data should have priority over enqueued calls, there are solutions like using two queues or a priority queue which could also be nice. ANnyway, the simplest change here is simply not to special case the callback calling once the event is set:
def producer(myEvent, i):
    # if not myEvent.is_set(): # no need for this
    print("Thread %d registered cb" %i)
    pipeline.put(reg_cb) # just enqueue the callback anyway
    # no "else" clause.  



Let's say - a lot of callbacks from multiple threads come, we checked
if not myEvent.is_set() in producer but event got set exactly after
the check, this behavior is not describable.

I don't see a problem there - the event where this hits will still be put in the pipeline and called in time.  If it must be called before the enqueued events are processed, then there is the need to do something, like using an internal lock in the MyEvent class - but nothing to worry otherwise.

Would there be any possibility of a thread registering callback twice
?

No - just use the queues and ut one item there each time one of yoru producers get data and that part should be ok. But your example didn't cover  how your producers get data in the real app - some care should be taken there. If they are dealing with network requests or file reading, you should be ok - these won't trigger duplicated events. But, for example,  if they are consuming from an external queue which should have "acks" for each item, you'd need to use a lock across your consumers to avoid posting the same item twice in the pipeline

In case if i want to ensure the callbacks don't just wait excessively
wait in the queue, i could have a queue size limit. Would that just be
enough ?

No - a queue size limit would block the consumer threads trying to post to the queue. While that will keep an excessive number of events to be called once the event is set, it won't make any of them "wait less time" in the queue.
If your callback can run for a limited number of events before the event is set, the event.wait call I suggested to be used in the consumer above can take a timeout - than you could rearrange the consumer in a way that, if the event takes too long to be set, to read and process some of the enqueued callbacks before blocking again (with another call to  event.wait(...).
Otherwise, if all your callbacks have to run after the event is set, and the problem is to limit the rate those calls take place after the fact, you have to implement some rate-limiter pattern in your consumer - (again, easier with the suggestion above of making all your callbacks pass through the consumer task, even after the event is set).
